# Passing array elements by ref

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# parameters by reference and .net garbage collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500851/c-sharp-parameters-by-reference-and-net-garbage-collection)

I was thinking of using ref arguments to limit the bounds checking of an array. For example the code of swapping two elements is :

```
class Test {
  int[] array;

  private void qSort() {
    ...blah...
    int temp = array[a];
    array[a] = array[b];
    array[b] = temp;
  }
}
```

which has 4 access to the array
the alternative will be :

```
class Test {
  int[] array;

  private void qSort() {
  ...blah...
    Swap( ref array[a], ref array[b] );
  }

  static void Swap(ref int a,ref int b) {
    int temp = a;
    a=b;
    GC.Collect();  // suppose this happens
    b=temp;
  }
}
```

which theoretically has only 2 access to the array

What confusing me is that I don't know what exactly happens when I pass an array element by ref. If Garbage Collector kicks in, while executing code in the Swap function, will be able to move the array ? or the array is pinned for the duration of the call ?

Mind that the above code is a simple test case. I want to use it in much more complex scenarios

Edit: As  BrokenGlass pointed out, this is answered by Eric Lippert here [C# parameters by reference and .net garbage collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500851/c-sharp-parameters-by-reference-and-net-garbage-collection)

The array will not be pinned and GCollector can move it and will update accordinly any ref to an element of it, that resides on the stack

Comment: Don't try to optimize prematurely, *especially* if you don't have deep knowledge of how the machinery works. Case in point: your second version (with `ref`) will actually be *much* slower than the first due to boxing (try it in a loop and see).

Comment: @Jon, I agree there is probably no point in doing this for performance reasons, but it does improve readability... And BTW, there is no boxing in that case

Comment: Panos, added a GC.Collect() to emphasise the point, roll back if you don't like it.

Comment: Above SO thread has an answer by Eric Lippert that should clarify the compacting/moving issue

Comment: @BrokenGlass, I ask this, for performance reasons. Pinning an array will of course have a penalty on the performance in the long run. Eric Lippert says that it doesn't happen, but leaves a question as whether managed references hide some kind of indirection or they have the same performance as unmanaged references (pointers). Anyway I consider the original question as answered/duplicate

Comment: I don't believe I said that **making a managed reference to an array allows it to be moved**. Rather, I said the converse: that **making an unmanaged pointer to an array requires it to be pinned**.

Comment: @Jon: Where is the boxing? Boxing happens when a value type is converted to a reference type, but there is no reference type here.

Comment: @Eric: You quote "does the garbage collector update even references created by passing reference parameters?"
with this answer:
"Yep. It would be rather fragile if it didn't." The only reason I could think that GCollector will update ref parameters on the stack is when the array is moved.

Comment: @PanosTheof: Suppose I told you that *if it rains, then the streets are wet*. That does not logically imply that it is raining! *If* the garbage collector moves a block of memory, *then* some mechanism exists so that outstanding managed references continue to be valid. Whether the garbage collector actually *does* move blocks of memory in these circumstances, and if it does, what *mechanism* it uses to keep managed references safe, I have no idea. I'm not an expert on the garbage collector. (Or, properly, collectors -- there are many implementations.)

Comment: I think the relevant quote from the linked question is "You're thinking about this like an unmanaged C++ programmer -- C++ makes you do this work, but C# does not. Remember, the whole point of the managed memory model is to free you from having to think about this stuff."

Comment: *which theoretically has only 2 access to the array* -- no, it still has 4. How can you imagine otherwise? And consider  the more straightforward `int tmpa = a, tmpb = b; a = tmpb; b = tmpa;` -- that still has 4. It should be obvious that you can't have less than 4 ... 2 reads and 2 writes.

Comment: @JimBalter: to the array, not to the array memory contents, which means that it does 4 bound checks if indexes "a" and "b" are valid vs 2 bound checks on the "ref" case

Comment: It would help if you said what you mean ... "access" is not at all the same as "bound check". As for bound checks, the compiler would optimize it down to 2 in your first code snippet.

Comment: I think you are correct. The current release of JIT of .NET Core it would optimize it, but I doubt that the standard .NET framework JIT would. Anyway when I post this, 7 years ago, the JIT will not optimize it. Since now we have Span&friends consider the question, the examples and the answers here, *very* outdated

Answer (score 1):

The `Swap` function still access the array 3 or 4 times, the Swap function does not offer any performance adavantage over the simpler code. It might be useful if it is reused.

```
static void Swap(ref int a, ref int b) 
{     
    int temp = a;  //<-- Here, a is in the array
    a=b;           //<-- a and b are in the array
    b=temp;        //<-- b is in the array
}
```

The garbage collector will not release memory you have a **reference** to, as happens when you pass by reference.

Answer (score 0):

The stack could look like this:

- qSort() has a reference to the array
- Swap()

So if GC.Collect() executes in swap there is still a reference to the array in qSort() which means it won't be collected.